# Joystick, clamping the control stick inside the joystick base

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touch, joystick

I have a circular joystick i created in SpriteKit, how do i clamp the smaller control stick inside of the larger joystick base and prevent it from going outside the joystick base programmatically.

The code setting up my joystick inside of my `didMove(toView:)` method.

```
var DPad = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dpad")
DPad.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
DPad.position = CGPoint(x: -270, y: -100)

var thumbNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "joystick")
thumbNode.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
thumbNode.position = CGPoint(x: DPad.position.x, y: DPad.position.y)
```

touchesBegan methods

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if thumbNode.contains(location) && isTracking == false {
            isTracking = true
        }

    }
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if isTracking == true {
            thumbNode.run(SKAction.move(to: location, duration: 0.01))
        }
    }
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        thumbNode.run(SKAction.move(to: DPad.position, duration: 0.01))
        if thumbNode.position.x > DPad.size.width || thumbNode.position.y > DPad.size.height {
            thumbNode.position = DPad.position
        }
    }
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
    if thumbNode.physicsBody?.velocity.dx > Float(0) || thumbNode.physicsBody?.velocity.dx < Float(0) {
        print("greater")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use `SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(upperLimit: radius), to: baseNode)`

To add it, just do `joystickNode.constraints = [SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(upperLimit: radius), to: baseNode)]`

Comment: hey! KnightOfDragon i have seen you elsewhere on this site before thanks for your help